# Why can''t I see my custom template when creating new page?

Tags: wordpress, templates, child-theming

I am just starting with getting to understand WordPress templates.

I have made a very simple template called "attribute_information_popup.php" and put in the folder "page_templates" in my child theme.

```
<?php 
/* 
 * Template Name: Attribute Information Popup Page
 * description: Template for making pages used in the product attributes information popup.
 */ 
?>

<h1>test</h1>`
```

When I go in to the "create page" I don't see my template showing up in the dropdown in the "page attributes" section on the right side of the page editor.

Comment: Maybe because you are using the incorrect folder name

"page-templates" with - instead of _

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#file-organization-of-page-templates

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to create any folder in your child theme. It's not mandatory. Secondly, check whether the same theme has been activated. I mean I have faced the same issue couple of times. I didn't see the page in dropdown. Then I saw that I have activated the parent theme. Then I activated the child theme and my issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks STBox, I checked, and the child theme is active. Still the same problem

Comment: I've tried to put the template in the root of the child theme, in the folder "page-templates" and the folder "page_templates", and no change